# Excluding npm modules from webpack in raeact-boilerplate

Tags: npm, webpack, yarnpkg, react-boilerplate

I have a project based on [react-boilerplate](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=react%20boilerplate&oq=react%20boilerplate&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3302j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

This seed project keeps server and client code in the same repo.

I want to use socket.io.

So I type:

```
yarn add socket.io
```

This adds socket.io to the `package.json`.

BUT I think this is then used by webpack to attempt to create a bundle.

Which then fails because socket.io is a Node.js module that depends on Node.js things like `fs`.

How can I stop webpack from attempting to bundle socket.io in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

Add the library name to the exclude array under `internals/config`  then `dllPlugin.defaults.excldue`.